# TLS 1.1 with non-SHA-1 message authentication code (MAC) implementation?

Tags: ssl, encryption, sha

I have a business requirement to use TLS 1.1 or greater and to not use SHA-1 (or RC4).

Are there any known-secure implementations of TLS 1.1 that do not use SHA-1 for the MAC?  I can't seem to find any. I am thinking I should just skip past TLS 1.1 at the moment if there are no secure MACs available.

Comment: Considering that anything other than MD5 or SHA-1 is not be part of the standard, how would you connect to servers that don't support this?

Comment: Both MD5 and SHA-1 are specifically identified as weak cipher suite components so it is allowable to not service those connections.

Comment: [Is HMAC-SHA-1 secure?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18575/13022)